# Keyboard is not present error on running Appium selenium script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium, appium-ios

macOS Mojave 10.14.4
Appium Desktop 1.13.0
selenium-java 3.141.59
testng 6.14.3
java-client 6.1.0

when the element properties are checked in Appium desktop the attribute visible is false, although it is visible and manually I can enter the user id in the app. tap and click on the Appium desktop also does not work.  I have tried to tap and click based on the co-ordinates from java code but no luck. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name=\"AlMobile\"]/XCUIElementTypeOther[5]\n"));
ele.click();
ele.sendKeys("user01");
```

error logs are available from the link:
https://github.com/facebookarchive/WebDriverAgent/issues/1121

Comment: I've been facing the same issue as well.